# Maximize the sum of difference between adjacent elements in a list [Python]

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem statement : There are N elements in a list ,arrange them in such a manner that maximizes the sum of absolute difference of adjacent elements multiplied by the index,

index starts from 1.

`(i=2,n=(elements in list))Σ i*abs(list[i-1]-list[i-2])`

Example :

**input list** :2 5 4

**output** : 13

**explanation** :

[2,4,5] -> 2*(2) + 3*(1) = 7

[2,5,4] -> 2*(3) + 3*(1) = 9

[5,4,2] -> 2*(1) + 3*(2) = 8

[5,2,4] -> 2*(3) + 3*(2) = 12

[4,5,2] -> 2*(1) + 3*(3) = 11

[4,2,5] -> 2*(2) + 3*(3) = 13

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried and what are your results?

Comment: Interesting problem though.

Answer (score 1):

You may not directly write out problems in this forum and expect people to solve them. This website is for fixing attempts, not making them. Also, this place is not for math problems, it is for programming problems, code to be more specific. I would suggest you go to https://math.stackexchange.com/ to ask about math problems.

However, same rules applies there. You have to show that you have an idea of how to solve the problem and that you have at least TRIED. They will give you knowledge of concepts, not solve problems. Just like an online teacher.

One more thing, do you even known what Python is? Since you put the tag.

I do have a way to solve your problem, however. You need to first sort the list (I'll give you Python code and run you through what it does along the way).

```
numbers = sorted(numbers)
```

Now, our numbers are sorted from beginning to end. Now, we must take the numbers in pairs of who's difference is greatest and who's is least (order doesn't matter since it is absolute value). This is easy because we have sorted the numbers from greatest to least. All we need to do is pick off a number from the end, then one from the beginning, then remove them both from the list so that we have a new beginning and end next time. Like this.

```
numbers = [1, 5, 4] #random collection of numbers; you can make it anything really
numbers = sorted(numbers)
import math
pairs = [] #A new list, collection, array, or whatever you want to call it
while len(numbers) == 0 or len(numbers) == 1: #Until there is one element or no elements left:
    pairs.insert(-1, [numbers[0], numbers[-1]]) #-1 means the first element going backwards. 0 means the first element going forwards. Please see below code for better explanation
    del numbers[0] #The first number from our original list of numbers is gone
    del numbers[-1] #The last number from our original list is gone


if pairs: #If our original list of numbers has a number
    pairs.insert(0, [numbers[0]]) #See below code for info on insert()
    del numbers[0]


for pair in pairs:
    numbers.extend(pair) #Instead of having groups of numbers, we now are putting them all into one list. Meaning, instead of something like [[5, 4], [4]] where [5,4] and [4] are separate groups, we have [5, 4, 4] where it is all one group

sum = 0 #The total sum in the end

for x in range(len(numbers) - 1, 1, -2): #Indexes in list start from 0. So to talk about the first number and the last number in a list with 5 numbers you would talk about the 0th element and 4th element (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). We are going from the last to the second element by twos (-2 signifies going backwards). 
    sum += (math.fabs(numbers[x] - numbers[x - 1])) * (x+1) #The formula you specified, keep in mind that our x is '2' in case of the '3rd' element, '0' in case of the first, and so on. math.fabs() is a function that does absolute value

print(numbers,sum, sep = "|||") #Numbers, remember was changed to be the best order it could be. I printed out the numbers, then a |||, then the sum
```

Please install Python 3.4 to run this program

---

I used the 'insert' command a few times during my program. In `insert(-1, [numbers[0], numbers[-1]]`, I inserted `[first_number, last_number]` into the last part of the list. This may be a bit over your head, google around a bit and you'll understand. That's what I did anyways (1 year ago) :P. KEEP IN MIND: numbers was sorted from least to greatest.

Comment: *ahem* This is not the place for commenting on the inappropriateness of a question; this should be a comment to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen it  a lot on questions, I have an answer though and was about to post  comment asking if I can post it. May I?

Comment: Sure, if you have an answer, go ahead I guess :).

Comment: Worked pretty hard on that one, took me a solid 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it would be to iterate through all permutations and calculate the total for each and then sort the resulting list as follows:

```
import itertools

input_list = [2, 5, 4]
result = []

for perm in itertools.permutations(input_list, len(input_list)):
    sum_diff = 0
    for i,pair in enumerate(itertools.izip(perm[:-1], perm[1:])):
        sum_diff += abs(pair[0]-pair[1]) * (i+2)
    result.append((sum_diff, perm))

print sorted(result)[-1]
```

Giving the result:

```
(13, (4, 2, 5))
```

The complete `result` list is:

```
[(7, (2, 4, 5)), (8, (5, 4, 2)), (9, (2, 5, 4)), (11, (4, 5, 2)), (12, (5, 2, 4)), (13, (4, 2, 5))]
```

Tested using Python 2.7